# How to set background image for all screen sizes?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an image to be set for relative layout background. In order to support all screen sizes (small to x-large) how large/small should its resolution  be set?

Comment: Is it a seamless image or non repeating?

Comment: @Dave non-repeating. A single image with a mark in centre, I want that mark be centred on every screen (regardless of size and density).

Comment: Your can use .9patch images for achieving it...

Comment: @DynamicMind 9 patch for background?

Comment: Yes convert this image into .9patch image

Comment: @DynamicMind what should be original resolution and size of image(before conversion) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put your background image in all drawable folders

```
xhdpi 960x720
hdpi 640x480
mdpi 470x320
ldpi 320x240
```